# Count most common titular words in a paragraph of text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to do a task where I open a text file, then count the number of times each word is capitalised. Then I need to print the top 3 occurrences. 
This piece of code works until it gets a text file with words that double up in a line.

txt file 1:

```
Jellicle Cats are black and white,
Jellicle Cats are rather small;
Jellicle Cats are merry and bright,
And pleasant to hear when they caterwaul.
Jellicle Cats have cheerful faces,
Jellicle Cats have bright black eyes;
They like to practise their airs and graces
And wait for the Jellicle Moon to rise.
```

Results:

```
6 Jellicle
5 Cats
2 And
```

txt file 2:

```
Baa Baa black sheep have you any wool?
Yes sir Yes sir, wool for everyone.
One for the master, 
One for the dame.
One for the little boy who lives down the lane.
```

Results:

```
1 Baa
1 One
1 Yes
1 Baa
1 One
1 Yes
1 Baa
1 One
1 Yes
```

Here is my code:

```
wc = {}
t3 = {}
p = 0
xx=0
a = open('novel.txt').readlines()
for i in a:
  b = i.split()
  for l in b:
    if l[0].isupper():
      if l not in wc:
         wc[l] = 1
      else:
        wc[l] += 1
while p < 3:
  p += 1
  max_val=max(wc.values())
  for words in wc:
    if wc[words] == max_val:
      t3[words] = wc[words]
      wc[words] = 1

    else:
      null = 1
while xx < 3:
  xx+=1
  maxval = max(t3.values())
  for word in sorted(t3):
    if t3[word] == maxval:
      print(t3[word],word)
      t3[word] = 1
    else:
      null+=1
```

Please help me solve this. Thank You!

Thank you for all the suggestions. After manually debugging the code, as well as using your responses, I was able to figure out that `while xx < 3:` was unnecessary, as well as `wc[words] = 1` ended up making the program double count the words if the third most occurring word occurred once. By replacing it with `wc[words] = 0` I was able to avoid having a counting loop.

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you learn some debugging skills. You can add `print()` statements to your code to see what it is doing. Print out the values of variables at key steps in your code. Then check if the values are what you expect. Alternatively, you can use a source-level debugger.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the counting code `wc` after the count shows `{'Baa': 2, 'Yes': 2, 'One': 3}` but your logic after I'm very confused by - what are you trying to do with the 2 `while` loops (note: they should both be `for` loops). The reason for your logic failure is you reset `t3` if there are less than 3 unique values greater than `1` which in your second case is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is super simple. But you'll need a few tools.

1. `re.sub`, to get rid of punctuation
2. `filter`, to filter out words by title case using `str.istitle`
3. `collections.Counter`, to count words (do `from collections import Counter` first).

---

Assuming `text` holds your para (first one), this works:

```
In [296]: Counter(filter(str.istitle, re.sub('[^\w\s]', '', text).split())).most_common(3)
Out[296]: [('Jellicle', 6), ('Cats', 5), ('And', 2)]
```

`Counter.most_common(x)` returns the `x` most common words.

Coincidentally, this is the output for your second para:

```
[('One', 3), ('Baa', 2), ('Yes', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator

fname = 'novel.txt'
fptr = open(fname)
x = fptr.read()
words = x.split()
data = {}
p = 0

for word in words:
    if word[0].isupper():
        if word in data:
            data[word] = data[word] + 1
        else:
            data[word] = 1

valores_ord = dict(sorted(data.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:3])

for word in valores_ord:
    print(valores_ord[word],word)
```